# My function output doesn't match when using different values in argument

Tags: r, function, if-statement

My function outputs a new df based upon specified parameters. I want my function to ignore an argument that has an `NA` value. It basically filters the original df based upon the specified parameters. But when i output the df to include different ranges of `subject`, the outputs do not always match reality.

Example data frame:

```
df1 <- data.frame(subject_col = rep(1:8, each =80),
                  response_col = sample(c('a', 'b'), 640, replace = T) ,
                  stimulus_col = sample(c("dog", "cat"), 640, replace = T),
                  rating_col = sample(1:4,640, replace = T))
```

My function:

```
my_fun<- function(stimulus, subject, response, rating){
  
      if (is.na(response)){
              newdata<-df1[df1$subject_col == subject & 
                           df1$rating_col == rating &
                           grepl(stimulus,df1$stimulus_col),]
      }else{
              newdata<-df1[df1$subject_col == subject_col & 
                           df1$rating_col == rating &
                           grepl(stimulus,df1$stimulus_col) & 
                           df1$response_col == awareness,]
      }
  return(newdata)
  }
```

The problem is that
`my_fun("dog", 5, NA, 1)`
outputs:

```
> my_fun("dog", 5, NA, 1)
    subject_col response_col stimulus_col rating_col
341           5            b          dog          1
344           5            a          dog          1
351           5            a          dog          1
359           5            b          dog          1
385           5            b          dog          1
387           5            a          dog          1
395           5            a          dog          1
```

but then `my_fun("dog", 1:8, NA, 1)` outputs the following:

```
> my_fun("dog", 1:8, NA, 1)
    subject_col response_col stimulus_col rating_col
82            2            a          dog          1
106           2            b          dog          1
211           3            b          dog          1
341           5            b          dog          1
495           7            b          dog          1
527           7            b          dog          1
535           7            b          dog          1
608           8            a          dog          1
632           8            a          dog          1
```

and `my_fun("dog", 1:6, NA, 1)` outputs with a warning:

```
> my_fun("dog", 1:6, NA, 1)
    subject_col response_col stimulus_col rating_col
37            1            b          dog          1
158           2            a          dog          1
165           3            a          dog          1
250           4            a          dog          1
310           4            a          dog          1
341           5            b          dog          1
359           5            b          dog          1
395           5            a          dog          1
444           6            b          dog          1
468           6            a          dog          1
Warning message:
In df1$subject_col == subject :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

Note:
I only used a single `if` statement in the example above, but i would like to do the same for all arguments in `my_fun`; where populating an argument with `NA` simply ignores the argument. Thanks for any help on this.

Comment: Just change the `==` to `%in%` if you are passing vector of length >= 1.  `==` is for elementwise comparison.  When you pass a vector of length > 1, it does recycling and this may create undesirable comparison i.e. `c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5) == c(1, 5)` instead, it would be `c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5) %in% c(1, 5)`

Comment: Amazing. Thank you! I'm still relatively new to R and this is a bit unclear to me. I'll study up on this; but it appears to now work as intended.

Comment: Side note: referencing `df1` inside a function when it is not explicitly passed as data is an anti-pattern for good programming techniques. Consider adding `data=` (or `x=`, ...) as your function's first argument and explicitly passing `df1` to it.